# Something similar to SelectedItem but for menu items?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

(I'm crap at english, I hope it's okay)

I have something similar to a combo box, but instead it's a "menuItem combo-box".
I tried to create a dynamic menu item that displays "History" objects dynamicaly.

And I have an issue with my code, I can't get the name of which item I click on..

Here is my wpf where you can see Click="myList_Click"; it's the trigger:

```
<Menu HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="525" IsMainMenu="True">
                <MenuItem Header="Menu" x:Name="myList" Click="myList_Click">
                    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style>

                            <Setter Property="MenuItem.Header" Value="{Binding name}"/>

                        </Style>
                    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Here is a part of MainWindow.cs :

```
 public MainWindow()
    {

      var list = new List<History>
            {
                new History() { name = "Guy1"},
                new History() { name = "Guy2"},
                new History() { name = "Guy3"},
                new History() { name = "Guy4"},
            };

        InitializeComponent();

        this.myList.ItemsSource = list;
    }

 private void myList_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DependencyObject obj = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;
        while (obj != null && obj != myList)
        {

            if (obj.GetType() == typeof(MenuItem))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(myList.SelectedItem.ToString());   
                break;
            }
            obj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(obj);
        }
    }
```

Lastly, my simple class "History"

```
public class History
{
    // "prop" puis "tab"
    public String name { get; set; }
    public String path { get; set; }
    public int time { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return name;
    }

}
```

I thought about SelectedItem but it doesn't work, SelectedItem doesn't exist for my MenuItem class. I tried some methods for my MenuItem but none gave me anything useful.

I want to click on a menuitem, and then display its name. (Example: When I click on guy1, a popup should appear and show "Guy1").

[image]

I need this String to manipuate my software later.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
    private void myList_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show((e.OriginalSource as MenuItem).Header.ToString());
    }
```